# Float divs left with 50vw

Tags: html, css

I have a bunch of divs that I want in 2 columns using 50vw and 50vw to make a perfect square. However when floating left, they don't go next to eachother but go on a new row. It has to be responsive so I cannot use fixed values. How can I make this?

HTML

```
<div>A</div>
<div>B</div>
<div>C</div>
<div>D</div>
<div>E</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
}

div {
    width: 50vw; 
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 50vw;
    background: pink;
}
```

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/ryp829mk/8/

Comment: Your CSS is applying the div rule to both the enclosing and enclosed `<divs>`.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap them in a div with explicit width = 100vw:

```
<div style = "width:100vw">
<div>A</div>
<div>B</div>
<div>C</div>
<div>D</div>
<div>E</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This makes the page have a horizontal scroll bar and makes it bigger than the page.

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with two things. First, the body has a margin so setting that to 0 allows for the divs to be flush with the page's edges. On mobile browsers, this now works like you expect. Second, the scrollbar gets in the way. This can be fixed by apply a style of `overflow: hidden` on the body.

**EDIT**

In order to keep the scrollbar, you would have to force the containing element (in this case the body) not to shrink when a scrollbar is added. To achieve this affect, you'd set the body's width to `100vw` (as suggested by another answer) and hide the horizontal scrollbar by adding `overflow-x: hidden` to the body's CSS.

Comment: Doing 50% width and 50vw height does not give a perfect square unfortunately.

Comment: @FirstLegion See the first part of my answer; removing the scrollbars would work. Or you can decrease the `vw` value until it fits inside the scrollbar. Finally, you can set the body to have a width of `100vw` and remove the horizontal scrollbar by adding `overflow-x: hidden` to the body. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/ryp829mk/9/

Comment: I still want the scrollbar so I cannot see a way to make it 100% of the screen minus the scrollbar with 100vw. Any number less than that will not work at all resolutions.

Comment: @FirstLegion 100vw overlaps with the space the scrollbars appear in. 100vw isn't the width you want if that's a problem; 100% is. In that case, the only solution to keep the height the same as the width is using JavaScript. Set the width of the boxes to 50% and use JS to set the height to the same number of pixels. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ryp829mk/10/